# Is there a faster/more efficient way of executing a grab and collate code? (Grab and collect specific data)

Tags: excel, vba, extract

I have an excel sheet that that uses a macro to order items in chronological order respective to their deadlines. This sheet then uses a separate macro to check if there is a value in the "hour" column (signalling time spent on this item). If there is a value then the code will extract the data and collate these instances into a ordered format - which can then be submitted as a daily timesheet. It may look VERY messy, but I am new so please be understanding of this.

I believe this code may also be the reason excel is not operating smoothly - I.E. ribbon icons are greyed until I hover over them and cell selection can lag (I have to move the excel window around the monitor screen to refresh and see new values after the code below has been run.)

Any comments please do not hold back.

Please click this link for the full file. 
[WORKBREAKDOWN STRUCTURE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C_sZINdalhi1Z2zMwzKAAyzvZg1gPu2Y/view?usp=sharing)

```
Public CalcState As Long
Public EventState As Boolean
Public PageBreakState As Boolean

Sub OptimizeCode_Begin()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

CalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Timesheet()

    Dim SrchRng As Range
    Dim PastRng As Range
    Dim Laststp As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim AdSt As Range
    Dim refe As Range


    Dim Hours As Long

    Call OptimizeCode_Begin


    Set SrchRng = Range("K4:K400")
    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If cel.Value <> "" Then

        'Setting up data cells to copy to temporary range
        Set PastRng = Range("L1")
        PastRng.Copy
        cel.Offset(, 1) = PastRng

        'Copy Proj number to temp range
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, -10)
        PastRng.Copy
        cel.Offset(, 2) = PastRng

        'Copy Proj name into temp range
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, -9)
        PastRng.Copy
        cel.Offset(, 3) = PastRng

        'Copy Activity into temp range
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, -6)
        PastRng.Copy
        cel.Offset(, 4) = PastRng


        'Copy cell x1 to right and paste in order in column S
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, 1)
        PastRng.Copy
        Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = PastRng

        'Copy cell x2 to right and paste in order in column T
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, 2)
        PastRng.Copy
        Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = PastRng

        'Copy cell x3 to right and paste in order in column U
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, 3)
        PastRng.Copy
        Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = PastRng

        'Copy cell x3 to right and paste in order in column V
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, 4)
        PastRng.Copy
        Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = PastRng

        'Copy hour to column X
        Set PastRng = cel
        PastRng.Copy
        Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = PastRng

        End If

        Next cel

        'Clear temporary sheet
        Range("L4:O200").Clear

    'do the same for above but now for the "Add Hour" column
    Set SrchRng = Range("J4:J400")
    For Each cel In SrchRng

    If cel.Value <> "" Then

        'Setting up data cells to copy onto
        Set PastRng = Range("L1")
        PastRng.Copy
        cel.Offset(, 2) = PastRng

        'Copy Proj number into temp range
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, -9)
        PastRng.Copy
        cel.Offset(, 3) = PastRng

        'Copy Proj name into copy temp range
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, -8)
        PastRng.Copy
        cel.Offset(, 4) = PastRng

        'Copy Activity into copy temp range
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, -5)
        PastRng.Copy
        cel.Offset(, 5) = PastRng


        'Copy cell x2 to right and paste in order in column S
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, 2)
        PastRng.Copy
        Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = PastRng

        'Copy cell x3 to right and paste in order in column T
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, 3)
        PastRng.Copy
        Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = PastRng

        'Copy cell x4 to right and paste in order in column U
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, 4)
        PastRng.Copy
        Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = PastRng

        'Copy cell x5 to right and paste in order in column V
        Set PastRng = cel.Offset(, 5)
        PastRng.Copy
        Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = PastRng

        'Copy hour to column X

    End If

    Set refe = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)

        If refe <> "" Then
            Set PastRng = cel
            PastRng.Copy
            Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = PastRng

            Else
            Set PastRng = cel
            PastRng.Copy
            Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1) = PastRng

        End If

    Next cel

    'clear temporary range
    Range("L4:O200").Clear

    Call OptimizeCode_End


MsgBox "Complete!"


End Sub
```

---

```
Sub OptimizeCode_End()

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
Application.Calculation = CalcState
Application.EnableEvents = EventState
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You current code is copying, but not pasting.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Good point, I will remove that. Thanks mate!

Comment: also assign this value to a variable `Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and increment this by 1 each time, rather than finding the end point again may help.

Comment: Why not just `cel.Offset(, 2).Value = cel.Offset(, -10).Value` etc. Skip the `Set` and `.Copy`

Comment: Nathan_Sav I removed the copy and now everything runs very smoothly. I think I was unnesscarily copying because I was not really understanding fully my VBA code. @PatrickK That's perfect thanks for the feedback, I'll try to trim down the code further. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is to add a

```
DoEvents
```

inside the loops. It won't make it faster, but you will not get the freeze effect.